How would you find the maximum of this function? $\sin(\frac{1}{x-1})+\sin(\frac{1}{x+1})$
Like the title says, I am trying to find the maximum of this function, which seems to be near 0.787. This is to "normalize" the function, so that the maximum is 1, so the x value is what I am looking for. Setting the derivative equal to 0 gives $\frac{\cos(\frac{1}{x+1})}{(x+1)^2}=-\frac{\cos(\frac{1}{x-1})}{(x-1)^2}$. Finding an exact value seems tricky.
I was looking at this originally because this function, along with a factor of 1/2, can be seen as an "average" of sin(1/x), every point is mapped to the average of the points a unit distance away from it. As you take successive averages, it all tends to 0, so I was looking for a way to renormalize every average in order to study the "inside" of the function.

The maximum isn't near 0.787

Let $$x_k=1+{1\over {\pi\over 2}+2k\pi}.$$ Then $$x_k+1=2+ {1\over {\pi\over 2}+2k\pi}\underset{k\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}2$$   Hence $$f(x_k) \underset{k\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}1+\sin(1/2)>1$$

It can be proved that the maximum is reached at $x=1-\frac{2}{3\pi}$. I'll update when I'm free, probably tomorrow.

Thank you @IntegralLover !

@RyszardSzwarc  Let $M$ be the maximum value of $f$. The OP did not claim $M=1$. They explained they wanted to know $M$, in order to divide $f$ by it, so as to obtain a function whose maximum value is $1$.

@IntegralLover For $x=1-\frac2{3\pi}$, the right handside of $\frac{\cos(\frac{1}{x+1})}{(x+1)^2}=-\frac{\cos(\frac{1}{x-1})}{(x-1)^2}$ is $0$, whereas the left handside is not.

@IntegralLover $1-\frac{2}{3\pi}\approx 0.7877934092$ while the value here is about $0.7872512279$

Thanks for letting me know, I was wrong. I used the formula of sum to product to change it to $2\sin\frac{x}{x^2-1}\cos\frac{1}{x^2-1}$, $1-\frac{2}{3\pi}$ is a solution of $\sin\frac{x}{x^2-1}=\cos\frac{1}{x^2-1}$. But the inequality $2ab\leq a^2+b^2$ cannot be applied in this problem, since the maxima is not obtained at $a=b$, although very close.

A really interesting question and some nice comments and answer too. Why was this closed? I can't imagine what other ways are there to improve this question to reopen it

@nnabahi Why is this question interesting? At the time of posting it, you already plotted your function and found the approximate value. What makes you think your post is answerable (i.e. finding the "exact value" is feasible)? Why did you accept the (non-)answer?

Too long for a comment:
It is worth sketching $f(x)=\sin\left(\frac{1}{x-1}\right)+\sin\left(\frac{1}{x+1}\right)$:

and you can see that the global maximum is at the second positive turning point (the first positive local maximum).
I doubt $\frac{\cos\left(\frac{1}{x+1}\right)}{(x+1)^2}+\frac{\cos\left(\frac{1}{x-1}\right)}{(x-1)^2}=0$ has nice analytic solutions.  The one you are looking for is approximately $0.7872512279$ at which point $f(x)\approx 1.5307060121$.

That's what I figured. I only now got around to checking the proposed $1-2/(3\pi)$, although I find it beautiful that such a simple looking number solves the first half of the equation.

@nnabahi $\frac{\cos(\frac{1}{x-1})}{(x-1)^2}=0$ when $\cos(\frac{1}{x-1})=0$ i.e. when $x=1+\frac{2}{(2k+1)\pi}$ for some integer $k$.  Here $1-2/(3\pi)$ uses $k=-2$.  For $x$ near $+1$, you have $\sin(1/(x-1))$ changing quickly and $\sin(1/(x+1))$ changing slowly, so the turning points of their sum will be near the turning points of $\sin(1/(x-1))$.
